# How to set the region for firebase function 2nd generation

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple function that I want to deploy in `us-east4`

```
const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
  
exports['user-document-sync'] = onDocumentWritten("users/{userId}", (event) => {
    console.log('Data Before',event.data.before.data());
    console.log('Data After',event.data.after.data());
});
```

I tried the following but it's not working:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions/v2");
exports['user-document-sync'] = functions.region('us-east4').firestore.onDocumentWritten(....
```

I can't find any information in the documenation

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore

Comment: It's not written anywhere in the documenation.  when you click on `onDocumentWritten(opts, handler)`  for example. The opts are only : `database, document, namespace`

Comment: No, it's right [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.md#firestoreondocumentwritten) in the API docs. You can see the first argument is `opts` which is a [DocumentOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.documentoptions) object, subclass of [EventHandlerOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.eventhandleroptions.md#eventhandleroptions_interface) that has a property `region`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:
The region should be passed inside the function arguments:

```
const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
  
  exports['user-document-sync'] = onDocumentWritten({
        document: 'users/{userId}',
        region: 'us-east4',
  }, (event) => {
```